# A Windows prog that converts between .doc or .docx and clean HTML suitable for editing with Sigil?

Tags: document-converter, ebooks

I am looking for a Windows program that converts from a .doc or .docx file (either of these formats will do) to "clean" HTML. By "clean" I mean in which the only formatting that's left is of a kind that makes the document suitable for editing using [Sigil](https://sigil-ebook.com/) for subsequent saving in the form of a reflowable e-book that's readable on Kindles and other devices.

Basically I need a program that does the same thing as Olly Cope's [Word2CleanHTML](https://word2cleanhtml.com/) but runs offline on Windows.